`gpg --pinentry-mode loopback` used to ask passphrase once but now it asks always
In short (Edit 1): How to make gpg -qd --pinentry-mode loopback out.gpg cache the passphrase for a period of time in the cli. It used to cache but now it doesn't.
Edit 2: I have tried this thing in both Kubuntu 24.04 Live iso image and a very old live iso image from 2017 called GParted live. In Gparted live iso, --pinentry-mode loopback caches the passphrase but not in Kubuntu live iso.
Edit 3: I have tested in Kubuntu 22.04, 23.10 and 24.04 using https://distrosea.com and gpg --pinentry-mode loopback symmetric decryption does indeed not cache the passphrase except 22.04.
And now the boring details:
In Kubuntu 22.04, I used to use these commands to create an encrypted file from stdin and to decrypt it:
gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --output out.gpg --symmetric - to encrypt
gpg --pinentry-mode loopback -qd out.gpg to decrypt.
While in a terminal session, the decryption command used to ask for the passphrase once for a certain time and I don't remember I did anything to get this behavior.
Now I have upgraded to Kubuntu 24.04 (by fully erasing the disk). But now, the decryption command above always asks for the passphrase in the same terminal session.
If I remove --pinentry-mode loopback, then the pinentry-qt dialog kicks and finally the decryption command stops asking for the passphrase for subsequent decryption commands with --pinentry-mode loopback.
So pinentry-qt correctly caches the passphrase but any subsequent--pinentry-mode loopback command requires a passphrase input with pinentry-qt in order not ask for the passphrase again.
I installed pinentry-tty and set the config in ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf to:
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty
and reloading the agent by:
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye.
This actually solves my problem by decrypting without using --pinentry-mode loopback. But what I want is the old (no config) behavior so I can get rid of updating all my scripts.

What is the question?

Edited the question.

The gpg-agent(1) manpage (man 1 gpg-agent) states:
OPTIONS
     Options may either be used on the command line or, after stripping off
     the two leading dashes, in the configuration file.
[...]
     --default-cache-ttl n
            Set the time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.  The default is
            600 seconds.  Each time a cache entry is accessed, the entry's
            timer is reset.  To set an entry's maximum lifetime, use
            max-cache-ttl.  Note that a cached passphrase may not be evicted
            immediately from memory if no client requests a cache operation.
            This is due to an internal housekeeping function which is only run
            every few seconds.
[...]
     --max-cache-ttl n
            Set the maximum time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.  After
            this time a cache entry will be expired even if it has been
            accessed recently or has been set using gpg-preset-passphrase.
            The default is 2 hours (7200 seconds).

so, by adding, e.g.
default-cache-ttl 60480000
max-cache-ttl 60480000

to $HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf and restarting gpg-agent, the cache entries will be kept for 700 days, or a bit less than two years. The cache is cleared when the gpg-agent is restarted, though (which can happen, for example, on reboot).

As the man page says: 'The default is 600 seconds'. gpg -qd --pinentry-mode loopback out.gpg always asks for the passphrase even within that default time period. Note that this is symmetric key encryption not public/private keys based. If I use public/private keys, then it caches the passphrase with --pinentry-mode loopback correctly.

Have you added the two lines from the answer to your $HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf and restarted gpg-agent (pkill gpg-agent)? On my system (OpenBSD 7.5, GnuPG 2.4.4), after killing the gpg-agent, the command gpg -d --pinentry-mode loopback file.gpg asks for the passphrase the first time, but each subsequent invocation doesn't ask for the passphrase (ie. it is cached).

I have tried those settings before asking the question but also after your comment. It still doesn't work.

That is strange, since I also tried creating the encrypted file using the gpg --pinentry-mode loopback --symmetric file, and decrypting it with gpg-agent -qd --pinentry-mode loopback file.gpg > file.out and the second command also didn't ask for a password on my system, with the gpg-agent using the above settings in the $HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf file.

Again, restarting gpg-agent is an important step; it doesn't dynamically reload the settings from the configuration file, but its every instance must be killed for the settings to take effect.

I restarted the gpg-agent but no, it still keeps asking for the passphrase within that time period.
